# Accessing localhost from other computers leads to URL redirect

Tags: ip, localhost

I'm using WampServer and I'm trying to access localhost (the WampServer homepage is stored on my computer) but can't if accessing from outside.

Using my external IP address this method works when I'm at home and I can easily see the configuration page:

[image: wampserver server configuration page]

But when I'm here at my workplace I get redirected to the site of the city immediately after accessing my IP address.

They're using a proxy but even if I connect using that proxy or not I still get redirected to the city website.

How can I view my homepage from an external access location?

Comment: Are you forwarding port 80 on your router to your Wampserver host?

Comment: I don't think I have the right to do that.

Comment: Your home router needs to forward port 80 to the computer hosting the Wamp or any other service you want to make available on the internet. This ought to get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Answer (score 1):

By which IP you trying to access your wamp page. It must be Public IP
i.e something not starting with 192.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x or 172.x.x.x. To access those from private IP your computer must be in LAN with your office.

So open http://www.whatismyip.com from your home computer. Try to browse the same IP from office. Also check the wamp is put online. In offline mode, it can't be access from other computers.

Comment: wamp is online and the ip that I got from whatismyip.com is the same as the one that I used to access

Answer (score 0):

In windows system.
Go to right corner bar. Click icon button.

Then, you will see the menu.
In the bottom, there is a "Put online", click it.
Your web are public now.

You can use "ipconfig" to check your ip address.

Finally, you can use this ip to access your server.